# Where to find definition of $Server['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].?

Tags: php

I'm transferring a website to a different server. I need to change all the file paths. In my config folder I found this line of code. Where might I find the definition of

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

in a standard PHP/MySQL website?

Comment: Are you sure it's not `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` ?

Comment: *"Where might I find the definition of..."* - [**A: right here**](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) ♫ ♫ ♫ *Gawd, I love that tune.*

Answer (score 0):

This is defined at the webserver's configuration.

For Apache it is the [`DocumentRoot`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot) directive in the configuration file; for nginx it is the [`root`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#root) directive.

Once you have updated the web server configuration correctly, the variable will point to the location specified there. You do not want to manipulate this variable "manually" in your code as it will lead to problems later on.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

Not

```
$SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

And `document root` will the (folder)path that you have placed at your server,And if you want to change it or view it,You can go through with your `configuration` of your server.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<pre>"; 
 print_r($_SERVER);
 echo "</pre>";.
 exit;
```

add this to top of your page, you will get all server variables... and dont forget to remove this snippet once you are done seeing the values.